# Best way to change pages with transition and animation effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, animation

There is a need for me to animate the page change on a website that i am building right now. Is there a way to do that without ajax and calling the next page and displaying it with all the effects thatbare required? Or shall i choose a something like React to do that since what i want in the end is the "SPA feel" to the end user?

Thanks in advance for reading this .

Comment: If you want to create an 'SPA feel' to the user, then you would be best spending your time creating an SPA. Any transitions you attempt to make between pages without it will be clunky.

Comment: Yeap i thought so. Just wanted to verify if someone with more experience has come through that in some other way. Do you have anything to propose for react page animations? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Well there is this new API proposed by google, the [Portals API](https://web.dev/hands-on-portals) but it is very new and they only work in Chrome Canary as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Try Animate.css

https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

there are nice effects for elements and combined with jQuery its that what youre looking for.